# JQUERY error : null or not an object. Any Jquery Ninjas that can help?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip

Any JQUERY NINJA's out there?

Getting an error in IE ?

**`'tip' is null or not an object`**

Here is the small script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       //Tooltips
        var tip;
        $(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){

            //Caching the tooltip and removing it from container; then appending it to the body
            tip = $(this).find('.tip').remove();
            $('body').append(tip);

            tip.show(); //Show tooltip


        }, function() {

            tip.hide().remove(); //Hide and remove tooltip appended to the body
            $(this).append(tip); //Return the tooltip to its original position

        }).mousemove(function(e) {
        //console.log(e.pageX)
              var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
              var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
              var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
              var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

             //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
              var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
              var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

            if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
                mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
                $(this).find('.tip').css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
            } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
                mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
                tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
            } else {
                tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
            }
        });

    });
```

Updated Code:(Can't seem to integrate your updated code into this)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Tooltips
    var tip = null;

    $(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){

        //Caching the tooltip and removing it from container; then appending it to the body
        tip = $(this).find('.tip').remove();
        $('body').append(tip);

        tip.show(); //Show tooltip


    }, function() {

        tip.hide().remove(); //Hide and remove tooltip appended to the body
        $(this).append(tip); //Return the tooltip to its original position

    }).mousemove(function(e) {
    //console.log(e.pageX)
          if ( tip == null ) return;


          var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
          var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
          var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
          var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

         //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
          var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
          var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

        if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
            mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
            $(this).find('.tip').css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
        } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
            mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
            tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
        } else {
            tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What line is this being reported on?

Comment: can you post HTML code please

Comment: @eberswine Note that you have `$(this).find('.tip')` instead of `tip` in your mousemove callback. Correct that.

Comment: Yes, corrected from above. That is the error line I am getting.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tenía varios problemas con el jquery, esta http://jsfiddle.net/vNBNz/4/ fue la solución definitiva a mi problema.

Thank you very much.

Test in:
http://www.redsaludcondorcanqui.com/establecimientos-de-salud/

view the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    $('.tip_trigger').each(function() {        
        var tip = $(this).find('.tip');

        $(this).hover(
            function() { tip.appendTo('body'); },
            function() { tip.appendTo(this); }
        ).mousemove(function(e) {
            var x = e.pageX + 20,
                y = e.pageY + 20,
                w = tip.width(),
                h = tip.height(),
                dx = $(window).width() - (x + w),
                dy = $(window).height() - (y + h);

            if ( dx < 20 ) x = e.pageX - w - 20;
            if ( dy < 20 ) y = e.pageY - h - 20;

            tip.css({ left: x, top: y });
        });         
    });

});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vNBNz/4/

As you can see, the above code works. In the live demo, notice this CSS rule:

```
.tip_trigger .tip { display:none; }
```

The above rule will hide all `.tip` elements, but only if they are inside a `.tip_trigger` element. This means that as soon as you append a `.tip` element to the BODY, it will be displayed because the "hide-rule" only applies to `.tip` elements inside `.tip_trigger`.

Comment: @eberswine How many tooltips (`.tip` elements) do you have on the page? If you have multiple, then you probably want to set `tip = null;` in the hoverout handler to clear the `tip` variable for the next hover/mousemove action.

Comment: @eberswine I've updated my code. ... I must admit that I'm uncomfortable with this solution. Using one single local variable to store the tooltip  doesn't seem like the best solution in a scenario where you have multiple tooltips. I'll think about alternative solutions.

Comment: @eberswine I've updated my answer with an alternative solution. I like this new solution much more.

Comment: Hi Sime, Here is my code that I am using, I am trying to implement your new way, but no luck :-(

Comment: @eberswine It would help if you could post the HTML source code (at least the relevant part that contains the .tip_trigger elements) or even if you could post a live demo of your page online.

Comment: @eberswine BTW, I have to go reinstall the OS on my sister's computer. I'll be away for 1-2 hours ...

Comment: Ok, great. I will post a demo here soon! By the way, the code that you first came up with is working fine... I was just trying to implement your new code.. thanks.

Comment: @eberswine I've updated my answer. The above code works, see the demo. Your code didn't work because you were hiding all .tip elements. But you have to hide them only if they're inside a .tip_trigger element.

Comment: @Sime YOU GOT IT!! PERFECT! Thanks so much for your kindness! You are the man!!

Answer (score 2):

This is because in IE `move` can happen before `hover`. Try [out this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vNBNz/). I did not reproduce this functionality in Chrome. And my IE test was IE9 beta.

So my guess is that it is failing on this line:

```
var tipWidth = tip.width();
```

Of the mousemove callback because `var tip;` is still `undefined`.

Comment: +1 That seems to be the cause of the error. But what to do about it? How to solve this issue in IE?

Comment: Yes, same... still not a solution

Comment: How do I test in "Edit this Fiddle" It doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @eberswine Just hover the text in the "Result" box (bottom right) with the mouse cursor. Then check the console (F12 in IE9).

Comment: @Šime Vidas - sry guys was playing some SC2 lol. glad you worked out a solution. I figured the cause of the problem was enough, because really from there it's pretty simple :)